# Open attribute table in qGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

What determines whether you can open an attribute table inqGIS?. I'd like to edit an attribute table for a raster in qGIS, but it won't me open the table. There's plenty in the help about editing attribute tables, but it doesn't say when you can/can't open them

Comment: There seems to be this commit https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/commit/c5ce39d7eefee8983a48b00026cf8281b8dbb964 about adding raster attribute tables but I don't know if there is UI for handling RATs.

Answer (score 1):

Vector data types have a table of attributes - which can be opened in QGIS.
Raster datasets generally do not have table of attributes
A raster datatype is a grid where each cell has a value.

Comment: Question is about raster attribute tables. GDAL can handle them through this class http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterAttributeTable.html#details but I don't know if QGIS supports RATs.